# Reindex single category programmatically

Tags: magento2, reindex

I would like to know if there is a way to reindex one single category programmatically in Magento 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The below code is used to reindex single category

Create **singleItemReindex.php** at `/pub/singleItemReindex.php`

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require '../app/bootstrap.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$categoryIds = ['6']; //pass catgory id
//list of indexers
$indexLists = ['catalog_category_product', 'catalog_product_category'];

foreach ($indexLists as $indexList) {
    $categoryIndexer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexList);

    if (!$categoryIndexer->isScheduled()) {
        try {
            $categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($categoryIds));
            echo $indexList . '<br>';
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Please try this and let me know it is working.

If you want to particular product reindex then you can use below code

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;

require '../app/bootstrap.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$params = $_SERVER;
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$productIds = ['100']; //pass product id
//list of indexers
$indexLists = ['catalog_category_product', 'catalog_product_category', 'catalog_product_attribute', 'cataloginventory_stock', 'inventory', 'catalogsearch_fulltext', 'catalog_product_price', 'catalogrule_product', 'catalogrule_rule'];


foreach ($indexLists as $indexList) {
    $categoryIndexer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerRegistry')->get($indexList);

    if (!$categoryIndexer->isScheduled()) {
        try {
            $categoryIndexer->reindexList(array_unique($productIds));
            echo $indexList . '<br>';
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks...